# Rails options_for_select set default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, collection-select

I have searched everywhere for this, and can't seem to find an answer.

I am trying to set the default value of my Language dropdown to English.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:native_language, Language.order('language ASC').all, :language, :language, :selected => [Language.find_by(:language => "English")] ) %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use select or collection_select:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:native_language, Language.order('language ASC').all, :language, :language, {:selected => Language.find_by(:language => "English").language}  %>
```

OR

```
<%= f.select :native_language, options_for_select(Language.order('language ASC').all, Language.find_by(:language => "English").language) %>
```

Comment: both return 'undefined method `map' for #<Language:0x007fa766c07438>'

Comment: <%= f.select :native_language, options_for_select(Language.order('language ASC').all, Language.find_by(:language => "English").id) %>

Comment: That is getting closer, but now all the dropdown options say 'Language:0x007fa766c07438' instead of the language name.

Comment: Yeah, then replace id with language. I assume language is a column in table.

Comment: That has the same result with Language:0x007fa766c07438

Comment: You are getting whole object of Language. In this , Language.find_by(:language => "English").id, replace id with attribute you want to see in dropdown. I guess attribute is language. So it would be "Language.find_by(:language => "English").language"

Comment: I did, and I am getting the same result. Here is my current code: <%= f.select :native_language, options_for_select(Language.order('language ASC').all, Language.find_by(:language => "English").id) %>    I feel like the problem is that it is not telling it to show language somewhere else. My original one called it twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120842/discussion-between-hasmukh-rathod-and-gwalshington).